# Display data from the response returned from axios. Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

Please help me ! i am very new to reactjs 
I am able to get response from web service . But i am unable to display the same on screen(mainly have to display in dropdown which i havn't tried yet as first step for me is to see the data on screen).

My webservice data :

[{"id":1,"db_name":"mysql","status":true,"urlRequired":true,"userNameRequired":true,"passwordRequired":true,"dbNameRequired":true}]

My code :-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class FetchDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     let currentComponent = this;
    axios.get(`http://10.11.202.253:8080/ETLTool/getAllDBProfile`)
      .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.data);

    currentComponent.setState({
        posts: response.data.items
      });


  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }

 render() {
    const renderItems = this.state.posts.map(function(item, i) {
      return <li key={i}>{item.title}</li>
    });

    return (
      <ul className="FetchDemo">
        {renderItems}
      </ul>
    );
 }
}

export default FetchDemo;
```

Error :-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I33Ov.jpg)

My response data via axios :-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT4v9.jpg)

Comment: Is there any key named `items` inside `data` object?

Comment: No .. since it has to be dynamic .. means even if i am not ware what the data is inside it should read the json dat a in key value pair and show

Comment: Then this will not work as you are trying to get `items` key from `data` object over here ```currentComponent.setState({
        posts: response.data.items
      });```, and because that key is not there you see an error.

Comment: Do you have any idea how we can dynamically do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above case, the mistake is with **understanding Component Lifecycle of React.**

Please take a look at the [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

ComponentDidMount occurs after the render has occurred.

Hierarchy will be 
1. constructor
2. componentWillMount
3. render
4. componentDidMount

if the code is modified with

```
render() {
    if (this.state.posts.length) {
    let renderItems = this.state.posts.map(function(item, i) {
      return <li key={i}>{item.title}</li>
    });
 }

    return (
      <ul className="FetchDemo">
        {renderItems}
      </ul>
    );
 }
```

OR

replace ComponentDidMount with ComponentWillMount

```
componentWillMount() {
     let currentComponent = this;
    axios.get(`http://10.11.202.253:8080/ETLTool/getAllDBProfile`)
      .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.data);

    currentComponent.setState({
        posts: response.data.items
      });


  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

Personal preference is the first suggestion as it checks "posts" state is initialized with Array or not if it's not an Array then map function will surely through an error.

Adding to it, there might be a problem with how you are taking the response from axios too.

```
currentComponent.setState({
            posts: response.data.items
          });
```

as I don't think response.data.items will give any data, as it should be limited to response.data only.

```
currentComponent.setState({
                posts: response.data
              });
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. I am able to see my data .

Answer (score 1):

I would remove `.items` since your response won't have that every time and just handle the data your receive in a render function if needed.

You could just do a conditional check when you set your state since I guess your db could be empty at some point:

`currentComponent.setState({ posts: response.data ? response.data : [] });`